# Wanting to do some prototyping with Java and databases. What driver to use?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I've been playing with an idea for a little program for a while now. It would involve players playing a simple game over the network, and would require the server to keep track of many things that would fit well in some sort of database system.

Since I'm just a student, and I'll probably end up testing it with a bunch of my friends and their laptops running different operating systems, I've opted to go with Java and Swing to ensure easy cross-compatibility.

I've never actually programmed anything with databases whatsoever, not with Java or any other language. I've done some research and looked into JDBC. Right now, I'm mainly hung up on which driver to use. I've not found a coherent list of anything except the 4 different types of drivers, but that doesn't help me choose a specific one.

I just want to get started quickly and have some database functionality, I don't care highly about performance or anything else, I'm pretty sure my small project won't ask for anything special that can't be done by every database system.

What is a good driver to get started quickly with? The server would be running on a Linux box, in case that matters. Bonus points if there is a bit of a guide on how to get started programming with databases using that driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the type IV driver for the database you'd like to use: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Derby, Hypersonic, etc.

The driver will be made available by the vendor as a JAR file that you'll add to your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Type 4 it is then. Is there a big difference between those databases, or is it just things under the hood?

Comment: @robrene - yes, there are significant differences between the databases.  But listing them all is beyond the scope of an SO question.

Comment: The JDBC driver makes connecting and executing SQL in Java similar from database to database, but the SQL you can send depends on the database vendor.  If you stick to ANSI SQL you should be (relatively) portable across databases.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Database u need to choose the Driver.
Driver is specific to the Database.
U can download the drivers from the Database website like oRacle or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about what driver to use, but I guess you really want to know is what RDBMS to use.

You could use PostgreSQL and get the JDBC drivers from [PostgreSQL site.](http://www.postgresql.org/)

---